# Kendo DataSource: how cancel an update request

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo UI grid and a datasource. When I call the Update method, I test a variable and if the condition is false, I don't want to send the request.

Currently I have:

```
 $scope.MySource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  update: {
            url: function (lista) {
                if (testVariable== true) {           
                    testVariable= false;
                    return "api/Liste/PutLista/" + lista.Id
                }
                else {
                    $scope.MySource.cancelChanges();
                }
            },
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                var auth = $window.sessionStorage.token;
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + auth);
            }
```

If `testVariable` is false I cancel the update but I still see an ajax request to

```
http://localhost:61927/index.html with PUT method.
```

How can I prevent a request if `testVariable` is false?

Comment: you have to check testVariable before you call MySource.sync() or whatever function you are using to trigger the update. Putting that logic in the url function will NOT stop the ajax request.

Comment: I trigger the update clicking on the Update button when i edit inline the grid....so i must intercept before the click event on the button?

Comment: Nope, fortunately you can also intercept it after the click event. Try out my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can intercept it right after you click on update. In your kendo grid, use the save event. This event is called every time you press update.

```
save: function (e) {
    if (testVariable === false) {           
        e.preventDefault();         //prevent default action that kendo does
        $scope.MySource.cancelChanges();
    }
}
```

If the variable is false, then you prevent the default action and do whatever you want (like cancel changes). If it is true, it will just take the default action and save your row.

Just make sure that the variable `testVariable` is accessible in  this event (global variable, or a local variable that you can set in this event).

Answer (score 2):

The `url` function is not the place to check if you actually want to make the request. I'm pretty sure there is no way to cancel once it has made it that far.

You may want to try using the [requestStart](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-requestStart) event instead. In some cases, returning `false` from the event handler will cancel the request (but not in all cases, which might be a kendo bug).

Otherwise, you can just overwrite the `sync()` function on the DataSource instance, do your checks, then call the base implementation if needed.

```
          $scope.MySource.sync = function () {
            if(customChecksPass) {
                kendo.data.DataSource.fn.sync.apply(this, arguments);
            }
          };
```

---

I also just re-read your question and realized you are using the Grid. The grid widget has a [save event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-save) that you can bind to, and cancel the call to the DataSource from there.

Comment: This would be a good alternative that doesn't rely on the grid's events.